# opterr declaration in getopt

Tags: c, getopt

The following is example code from http://www.gnu.org. As surely most of you will see, it's getopt and I am having a question about the variable declarations. Why is there no type or anything written in front of

```
opterr = 0;
```

I have never seen that before.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int aflag = 0;
  int bflag = 0;
  char *cvalue = NULL;
  int index;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;


  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'c':
        cvalue = optarg;
        break;
      case '?':
        if (optopt == 'c')
          fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if (isprint (optopt))
          fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf (stderr,
                   "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                   optopt);
        return 1;
      default:
        abort ();
      }
  printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
          aflag, bflag, cvalue);

  for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
    printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting that you don't ask where `optarg` comes from.

Comment: The IDE of your choice might support the function "Show Declaration" (or something similar). For example in Eclipse CDT it is the button "F3", alternativ you can right click on the variable and select this function by hand.

Comment: @user0042 - :D yeah... haven't thought about that tbh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`opterr(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opterr) is declared as an extern variable in `unistd.h`:

```
extern int optind, opterr, optopt;
```

So it's a global variable defined in a different translation unit, in this case your standard C library.

The reason for setting it to 0 is also explained in the manpage:

> If `getopt()` does not recognize an option character, it prints an error message to stderr, stores the character in `optopt`, and returns `'?'`. The calling program may prevent the error message by setting `opterr` to 0.